# Junit test case for kafka stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, spring-kafka

I have a used kafka aggregation to calculate end-to-end latency.

```
KStream<String, TransactionCloudEvent> ktable = builder.stream(topicName,Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), cloudSerde));

 ktable
                .peek((key, value) -> log.info("Incoming record - key {} , value {} ", key, value))
                .filter((k,v) -> v.getData().getEvent().startsWith("start"))
                .mapValues((k,v) -> { --- }
```

now I am trying to get test coverage for the above code

```
String bootstrapServers = kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers();
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(
                ImmutableMap.of(
                        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                        bootstrapServers,
                        ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                ),
                new StringSerializer(),
                new StringSerializer()
        );
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, "testcontainers", "rulezzz")).get();
```

but the execution is not able to reach the ktable .
Please help.

I tried with TestContainer as well, but no luck